# Auto format if statements

Tags: visual-studio-2010, key, shortcut

I find a lot of the time when I am coding if statements, if I alter them to have an if become an if && || instead, I'll end up with indents all over the place. Some will be tabbed once, some tabbed twice, turning back to once and back to twice sometimes - depending on how many changes I have done.

I was curious if there was a key that would auto format indents so my code would look like it was properly indented again. Thanks a lot for any answers.

Comment: What language? The tooling is often very different for C++ than it is for, say, C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default shortcut key to auto-format code in Visual Studio is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>

Other environment settings might also have it configured as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: If this thing does nothing, you have to select a whole function, it would seem.